# How FileOutputStream and FileChannel works together

Tags: java

I have small doubt to be cleared.

I've studied that Filechannel mostly interacts with Buffer types only for read and write.

What if we are using Fileoutputstream with FileChannel together? I am not able to understand the flow in between, how they works together with given code snippet.

```
 FileChannel channel = new FileOutputStream(TokenFile, append).getChannel();
```

some code then

```
 channel.write(buffer);
```

My understanding says, channel is reading from buffer and then channel passing it to File output stream(Object) and then that output stream is writing to a file in append mode ? Please correct me if am wrong ..!!

Can anyone please help me to clear my doubt ?

Comment: First tell us why you would contemplate such an inane procedure. There is no 'channel reading from buffer' here.

Comment: @EJP, What do you mean by "There is no 'channel reading from buffer' here" ? That's how channels works..No ? My only concern here is how Fileoutputstream with FileChannel working together ? And how it could be inane to understand this ?